# How to make "grep" output complete word that includes the match?

Tags: grep

I would like grep to print out all complete words that include the match.

Google did not help me. Here what I tried:

```
cat file.txt
21676   Mm.24685    NM_009346   ENSMUSG00000055320
20349   Mm.134093   NM_011348   ENSMUSG00000063531
12456   Mm.134000   NM_011228   GM415666

grep -o "ENSMUS" file.txt
ENSMUS
ENSMUS
```

Desired output:

```
ENSMUSG00000055320
ENSMUSG00000063531
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can `ENSMUS` be anywhere else than start?

Comment: No, always at start and preceded by tab. Thanks.

Comment: With GNU awk: `awk '/ENSMUS/' RS='[\t\n]' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```sh
grep -wo "ENSMUS[^[:blank:]]*" file.txt
ENSMUSG00000055320
ENSMUSG00000063531
```

Here `[^[:blank:]]*` will match 0 or more characters that are not whitespaces. `-w` will ensure full word matches.

Comment: worked as desired! Thanks also for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

To extract ENSEMBL mouse accession numbers without the version number:

```
grep -Po 'ENSMUS\w+' in_file
```

With the version number:

```
grep -Po 'ENSMUS\S+' in_file
```

Here,
`\w+` : 1 or more word characters (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`).
`\S+` : 1 or more non-whitespace characters (you can also be more restrictive and use `[\w.]+`, which is 1 or more word character or literal dot).

Here, GNU [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-o` : Print the matches only (1 match per line), not the entire lines.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)
[perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Comment: Thanks, even less typing :)